# How to use foreign keyboard

Tags: keyboard, language-support

I believe I have the keyboard I want installed (PL) and I am used to using alt+letter (windows) or control+letter (mac) to insert foreign letters. I am struggling to figure out how to do the same here. In the top right it shows the keyboard I want active.

Comment: How about I say it's for 15.04? I am pretty sure this hasn't changed

Comment: Nah, I would just remove the tag ;-) There done.

Answer (score 1):

You can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd>  + <kbd>U</kbd> . After that you'll see an `u` inserted. You can then type the unicode for the character to insert, then <kbd>SPACE</kbd> and the input is changed into the character.

Another way to insert characters with accents easy is t use a keyboard setting with so called dead keys. If you then type a single quote (`'`) it does nothing. A space will insert the quote. But typing <kbd>e</kbd> it will produce an `é`. You can change it using `System Settings -> Text Entry`. You can also install additional keyboard layouts there.

Good luck!